# Do we have a term for this analysis combination?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, titles

I'm in the middle of a programming article, and I don't know if this thing has a name or not.

Lot's of times you can analyse something in isolation. But as soon as you put that thing among other things, you have to analyse the relationships too. For example, if you want to analyse a word individually, you might use morphology, phonetics, and phonology. But if you want to analyse that word in a sentence, you should stick to syntax, intonation, and stuff like that.

What I'm searching for is a title for **"things can be analysed both in isolation, and in context, and these analyses are different from each other in approach, and in result."**

Do we have a term for that?

Comment: Compare and contrast?

Comment: Not that one. Doesn't convey what I have in mind. I go for something like *isolation & context*, but I do like to see if it already has a name or not.

Comment: 'analysis in context'?

Comment: La double articulation linguistique.

Comment: No, they're not really helpful in conveying what I mean.

Comment: Actually in Arabic a similar concept is named **Tajzia & Tarkib** or **Sarf & E'rab** analysis, which simply means that you analyze a word's attributes without considering its role in a sentence, or analyzing its role *inside* a sentence.

Comment: Have you tried asking on linguisticsSE?

Answer (score 2):

I am concerned that you used a single-word-request tag on the question, because all of the candidates appear to demand contrasting pairs.

The **textual-contextual** dichotomy seems analogous to your situation in a slightly different realm, as does **connotation-denotation**.

In some contexts, you might even consider **internal-external** or by extension **instrinsic-extrinsic**

Comment: Nice pairs. I actually liked textual-contextual. But based on the deductiveness issues I'm seeking here, I guess *textual* might be replaces with something that conveys *isolation* more.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is a word but if you are looking for a succinct phrase , how about "Semantic Relativism" ?

Comment: Thanks for answering, but how it's related?